# Symfony 6.3 Error unable to fetch the response from the backend when accessing dynamic route

Tags: symfony, symfony6, symfony-routing

I have a Symfony project in which all the routes work well except the only dynamic route `service/{path}`. I get the error **"# unable to fetch the response from the backend: read tcp 127.0.0.1:52258->127.0.0.1:51903: wsarecv: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."** every time I try to access the route

below is my controller code

```php
    #[Route('/service/{path}', name: 'service')]
    public function viewService(ServiceListRepository $serviceList, string $path): Response
    {
        $service = $serviceList->getService($path);    

        return $this->render('services/service.html.twig', [
            'service' => $service,
            'path' => $path
        ]);
    }
```

What is the cause and how do I solve it?

This is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

services:

###> symfony/mailer ###
  mailer:
    image: schickling/mailcatcher
    ports: ["1025", "1080"]
###< symfony/mailer ###

###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  postgres:
    image: postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION:-15}-alpine
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: databasename
      # You should definitely change the password in production
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mypassword
      POSTGRES_USER: databaseuser
      
    volumes:
      - database_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:pgdata
      # You may use a bind-mounted host directory instead, so that it is harder to accidentally remove the volume and lose all your data!
      # - ./docker/db/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data:rw
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
    ports:
      - 5432:5432

###> adminer setup begins ###
  adminer:
    image: adminer:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
###> adminer setup end ###
  


volumes:
###> doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
  database_data:
###< doctrine/doctrine-bundle ###
```

Comment: Most likely it´s your webserver setup, how are you doing it? why are there multiple ports? Maybe you should try to see if this error appears also with standard setup on port 80/443  or share more infos about your webserver and configuration

Comment: Also checking if service exists and return an exception if it does not, might help...

Comment: @johnSmith I have included my setup